# Android Studio Error: Class too large: project/co/dom/R$id (app:processDebugResources)

Tags: android, class, android-layout

I am beginner to Android Studio and not a programmer either.
Our team is building a rather big android APK; lately we encounter this error which we do not have solution. When it happens we simply cannot continue with the project; we have to retreat back from the last addition we make.
This error occurred as I tried to improve the XML file. It is confusing as to where to locate the source of the error. Perhaps any of you may have solution or suggestion.
Any help will be appreciated.
[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjlpD.png)
[https://pastebin.com/LqZYtP2t][2]

Comment: Have you tried clean & build your project. And also try deleting the build folder in the app directory and try rebuilding the project.

Comment: Hi @Ray -- Can you please add the xml before/after the changes you made? It would help others see what may have gone wrong by looking at what was added that may have caused the issue. Please make sure to remove any sensitive information, such as passwords, etc (replace with *****) . Also - please add the error as well

Comment: a newbee to Stackoverflow; I am still trying to find way to share the XML

Answer (score 0):

One possible explanation for your issue is that the xml file does too much, perhaps you could try to split it in multiple class instead.

Comment: Charlix2001, to manage one asset requires three pages of xml approx. 5923 lines of code each for REGISTRATION; similar for REPLICATE, and UPDATE. So far there are 13 assets in the APK and will be added more in the future.